# Adding a default value to html input element freezes the increment/decrement functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html-input

Here's one line of my table:
[image]

In the last column **Quantité**, the user is supposed to increment/decrement that field and the value will increase or decrease accordingly.

I have achieved this by adding an **input** element in the last column and making its **type : number.** The increment/decrement functionality gets added automatically.
This is much simpler and easier than doing two buttons and all the extra pain that will go with that.

```
  <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="qte"
                                min="0"
                                max="200"
                              />
```

Anyway, since the initial values will be retrieved from the database, I have to set a default value to that last column:

```
 value="5"
```

But, when I do so nothing happens when I click on increment/decrement in the input field.
Any idea why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: How do you do so? show the code where you are setting the default value? are you doing at the rendering time or after the fact with Jquery? Just adding value="5" should not cause any issue. Secondly, and importantly, IDs are ment to be unique. Every element should have a unique ID. In our case the qte in every row is id="qte"

Comment: @NawedKhan yes, adding value="5" sets the default value as 5, displays 5 and freezes the increment/decrement functionality. In other words, I click and nothing happens.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp  ===> value - Specifies the default value

Comment: I do not agree. Adding value has nothing to do with anything. It is not even a JavaScript or JQuery issue. Here is an example and it works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/avL06gy8/   you are not sharing the javascript code. When and where does it freeze? there is more to what you are sharing.

Comment: You probably have a onchange attached to your input that is causing the issue.

Comment: For some reason in my code, if I add value the increment/decrement simply doesn't do anything anymore. I've tested the code you've sent me and I see that adding value there is not an issue. I've copied and pasted it in my project and I still get the same problem. So it has something to do with my code.

Comment: Apparently this has something to do with React somehow. I've started a clean project and pasted the code you sent me and there's exactly the same problem..

Comment: I've tried in React App and also getting your problem, I don't know the reason, but it looks like you will need to do two buttons to change the value :/ @AhmedGhrib

Comment: @Gonzalo Yes apparently, I will have to do that. Thank you for letting me know I am not alone :)

Comment: @Gonzalo I have just found this npm package. It might solve our problem : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-numeric-input

Comment: Is this issue related to react js or vannilla javascript ??

Comment: That might be a solution, if you tried it and it's solved, just answer your own question and close it :) @AhmedGhrib

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement this is React app, then replace `value` with `defaultValue`. Check the react doc for more about uncontrolled components [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). Check the snippet

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div> <p>Input React Sample</p>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" defaultValue="5"/>
    </div>
    
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render( < Hello / > , document.getElementById("app_root"));
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.2.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app_root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">

  </script>
</body>
```

If the issue is in html, there is no need for default value, just add `value="your_initial_value"`

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="5" />
```